# Change global variable in threading

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, global-variables

I am working with threading and multiprocessing and encounter an issue, here is my code:

```
xxx = []

def func1(*args):
    #do something 1
    global list
    xxx.append('x')

def func2(*args2):
    func1x = partial(func1, ...(*argsx)...)
    with multiprocessing.Pool(3) as pool: pool.map(func1x, arg)

def func3(arg3):
    While True:
        try:
            # do something 2
            global list
            print(list)
        except:
            continue
def main():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=func2, args=(*args2))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=func3, args=(args3))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()

main()
```

My code block run smoothly without any error with these nested multiprocessing and threading.

Problem is eventhough I tried to set a new global variable for `xxx` in `func1()`, the `print` command in `func3()` still print `[]` instead of `['x']` as I expected.

I use `while` loop to wait for the func1() to declares new variable of `xxx`, still not working.

How can I use new global variable everytime it's changed in a running thread?

Comment: "list" is a keyword, you should'nt use it as a name for your variables.

Comment: Yes, I just call it as "list" here for example, not in my code. Btw, I edited "list" into "xxx"